# Yeoman with Bootstrap: How to choose jQuery version?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I built a custom Yeoman generator that loads, among others, Bootstrap 3.

`bower.json`-Template:

```
{
  "name": "<%= _.slugify(appname) %>",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {<% if (includeBootstrap) { %>
    "bootstrap": "~3.0.3",
    "respond": "~1.4.2",
    <% } %>
    <% if (includeD3) { %>
    "d3": "~3.4.4",
    "colorbrewer": "~1.0.0",
    <% } %>
    "modernizr": "~2.6.2"
  }
}
```

As you might know, Bootstrap 3 includes jQuery as dependency, here's the `bower.json` of Bootstrap:

```
{
  "name": "bootstrap",
  "version": "3.0.3",
  "main": [
    "./dist/js/bootstrap.js", 
    "./dist/css/bootstrap.css", 
    "./dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot",
    "./dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg",
    "./dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf",
    "./dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "_*",
    "docs-assets",
    "examples",
    "/fonts",
    "js/tests",
    "CNAME",
    "CONTRIBUTING.md",
    "Gruntfile.js",
    "browserstack.json",
    "composer.json",
    "package.json",
    "*.html"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">=1.9.0"
  }
}
```

As a result of this, the generated yeoman app contains a folder `bower_components/jquery`, with the newest jQuery version (2.1.0 or something) - which, unfortunately, does not support IE8.

I, unfortunately, need IE8 support.

Now, **how do I tell my app that it should load a Bootstrap that includes a `bower.json` which has ~1.9.0 instead of >=1.9.0?**

Second question: Why is jQuery installed on the same hierarchy level as Bootstrap, i.e., in `bower_components/jquery/`, and not in `bower_components/bootstrap/bower_components/jquery` or something, as it is a sole dependency of Bootstrap and not specified as such in my yeoman `bower.json` template?! That's something I find very confusing.

Comment: I think bower does this automatically if you install bootstrap and `jquery#1.x` (it notices the jquery dep. for bootstrap is already installed and will divert bootstrap to use that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@puredevotion's comment is correct. What I did to resolve this: I explicitly added jQuery in my bower.json. Bootstrap recognizes this and does not load jQuery itself.

Here is my updated bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "<%= _.slugify(appname) %>",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {<% if (includeBootstrap) { %>
    "bootstrap": "~3.0.3",
    "respond": "~1.4.2",
    <% } %>
    <% if (includeD3) { %>
    "d3": "~3.4.4",
    "colorbrewer": "~1.0.0",
    <% } %>
    "modernizr": "~2.6.2",
    "jquery": "~1.9.0"
  }
}
```

I still don't know the answer to my second question though.

Answer (score -1):

You need [css3-mediaqueries-js](https://github.com/livingston/css3-mediaqueries-js) take a look at [this](http://www.telegraphicsinc.com/2013/10/using-bootstrap-3-with-internet-explorer-8-ie8/) for how to use it in your situation.

Comment: Media queries work fine in IE8 with respond.js. Your answer has got nothing to do with jQuery.